# Token Generation in SailsJs v1.0

Tags: mysql, mongodb

How to generate token in Sails v1.0 as in Sails v0.12 we can use custom middleware but the same is Deprecated in sails v1.0 ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is quite what you're looking for, but if you add the npm package sails-hook-organics, there is a helper: sails.helpers.strings.random() that will giva a random string to use as a token, you can pass in the string 'url-friendly' as an argument to get a url friendly token.

https://github.com/sailshq/sails-hook-organics

Comment: If you are looking to email the token you can also use 'url-friendly' like so: `const token = await sails.helpers.strings.random('url-friendly');`